# Нормальное получение данных из AJAX запроса

Tags: javascript, ajax

Есть вот такая вот AJAX функция:

```
function requestFunc(route) {
        const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open("GET", route, true);
        request.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (this.readyState === 4) {
                if (this.status === 200) {
                    if (this.responseText != null) {
                        varForReturn = JSON.parse(this.responseText)
                    } else alert("Данные не получены");
                } else alert("Ошибка" + this.statusText)
            }
        }
        request.send(null)
    }
```

Но данные могу получить из нее, только если переменная(varForReturn) была объявлена вне этой функции.А мне нужно, получать значение из запроса, чтоб вся эта функция(requestFunc) его возвращала return'om. Чтоб работала вот такая конструкция:

```
var item = requestFunc("какой-то url")
```

Пробовал в самой функции, до запроса, объявлять переменную, и потом, на том же месте, где `varForReturn` приравнивать ее к результату запроса и возвращать, это не работает, возвращается значение, назначенное, при объявлении функции. Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вернуть значение из события или из функции обратного вызова? Или хотя бы дождаться их окончания](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%98%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b6)

Answer (score 0):

> А мне нужно, получать значение из запроса, чтоб вся эта функция(requestFunc) его возвращала return'om.

Можно воспользоваться вот таким вот вариантом получения данных. С асинхронными действиями не получится работать в точности как с синхронными. У асинхронности свои особенности.

```js
(async _ => {
  try {
    const item = await requestFunc('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
    console.log(item)
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
})()

//
function requestFunc(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fetch(url)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(json => resolve(json))
      .catch(reject)
  })
}
```